# Size of String array passed as argument to main method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

Is there any default size of String Array passed as argument to main method of java Class in eclipse or is it determined at runtime by counting the number of argument passed in.

public static void main(String[] args) {
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is determined at runtime, depending on the number of arguments passed to the program.

Comment: However I have heard in Java, "normal" arrays are fixed-size and String[] looks like a simple array to me.

Comment: Yes, arrays are fixed-size, meaning you can't change the size of an array. An array can still be created with any size at runtime.